# Prove that there are infinitely many values of $α$ for which $f(x)= x^{7} +15x^{2} − 30x + α$ is irreducible in Q[x]

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, integral-domain

Prove that there are infinitely many values of α for which $ x^{7} +15x^{2} − 30x + α $  is irreducible in $Q[x]$. I know that an irreducible polynomial is a non-constant polynomial that cannot be factored into the product of two non-constant polynomials. I need a general way to show irreducibility. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, corrected

Comment: Fortunately, my answer is also true for this polynomial :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show with the Eisenstein-criterion that every $\alpha$ divisible by $5$ , but not divisible by $25$, does the job.